# Link to the pending review after the edit is submitted

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

> **Thanks for your Edit!**
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

I'm sure you've seen that, somewhere at some time in the past.  Those who know, can go to their own profile, activity, suggestions (or all) and *then* click on the suggested edit link for the most recent edit.  Granted, thats a few clicks.

For those that don't know all the ins and outs of the profile, this is just a statement that reads much like "Thank you for your call, your call is important to us."

The request is to provide a glimpse into the "where is this suggested edit" in the process? Just make that "peer reviewed" a link to the review task that was generated.  It becomes much easier for those who go back to the post and wonder why the review is taking so long on a site and it helps introduce the peer review process (this *isn't* random people clicking random buttons <sub><sup>most of the time</sup></sub>).